# filtering several lists from reference list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have 4 lists of about 150M lines each and I need to filter them out by duplicates on list one.

```
lst1=['1','2','1','3']
lst2=['a','b','c','d']
lst3=['a','b','c','d']
lst4=['a','b','c','d']
```

magical code that give me this:

```
lst1=['1','2','3']
lst2=['a','b','d']
lst3=['a','b','d']
lst4=['a','b','d']
```

I tried to:

```
    set1=list(set(list1))
    newlst2=[]
    newlst3=[]
    newlst4=[]
    for i in set1:
        newlst2.append(lst2[lst1.index(i)])
        newlst3.append(lst3[lst1.index(i)])
        newlst4.append(lst4[lst1.index(i)])
```

the problem is this takes forever due to the huge lists I am using.
is there any way to optimize this?

I apologize the archaic way of coding but I am a life-sciences scientist :)

EDIT for clarification: the lists are not independent, lst1[1],lst2[1],lst3[1],lst4[1] are 4 measurements of the same "thing". lst1 is a unique identifier that must only appear once, hence the need to remove duplicates and expand that removal to the other lists.
ie.: removing 1 from lst1 (because its duplicated) should lead to the removal of "c" from lst2, lst3 and lst4 because they are in the same position.
lst1[3] is duplicated --> so lst1[3], lst2[3], lst3[3] and lst[4] are removed.

picking on Chris_Rands answer:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

def filter_lists(master_lst, lst2, lst3, lst4):
    unique = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(master_lst))
    unique_idx = [master_lst.index(item) for item in unique]
    for lst in (master_lst, lst2, lst3, lst4):
        yield list(itemgetter(*unique_idx)(lst))

lst1=['1','2','1','3']
lst2=['a','b','c','d']
lst3=['a','b','c','d']
lst4=['a','b','c','d']

print(list(filter_lists(lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4)))
# [['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
```

the slow part of the process is still to index every element of unique against the master_lst. Since OrderedDict returns retains the initial order of the list I used this instead of index:

```
unique_idx = []
total_counts=len(unique)
master_count=0
unique_count=0

while total_counts>0:
    if unique[unique_count]==master_lst[master_count]:
        unique_idx.append(master_count)
        unique_count=unique_count+1
        total_counts=total_counts-1
    master_count=master_count+1
```

it seems faster.
wow, creating the unique_idx went from several hours to a couple of seconds!

Comment: I understand why 1 was removed from lst1. But why C from the others? Is it a duplicate element if the element exists in any other list? If so why are a, b, and d still there?

Comment: I also don't understand, explain clearly the logic, is each list independent or not? Does the order matter when you filter out the duplicates?

Comment: removing 1 from lst1 (because its duplicated) should lead to the removal of "c" from lst2, lst3 and lst4 because they are in the same position.
ie: lst1[3] is duplicated --> so lst1[3], lst2[3], lst3[3] and lst[4] are removed.

Comment: Looks like a job for `numpy`. Read in data as 2 dimensional numpy array, find the column indexes to delete and use the `.delete()` function.

Comment: in case of duplication, should your resultant lists be containing the elements corresponding to first elements in `list1` or any value will work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be uniquely your list (while preserving the order) using `OrderedDict.fromkeys()`, then get the unique indexes using `list.index`, then simply iterate over all `list`s and extract the unique indexes using `itemgetter()`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

def filter_lists(master_lst, lst2, lst3, lst4):
    unique = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(master_lst))
    unique_idx = [master_lst.index(item) for item in unique]
    for lst in (master_lst, lst2, lst3, lst4):
        yield list(itemgetter(*unique_idx)(lst))

lst1=['1','2','1','3']
lst2=['a','b','c','d']
lst3=['a','b','c','d']
lst4=['a','b','c','d']

print(list(filter_lists(lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4)))
# [['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
```

Comment: This is insanely fast!